# How to make Toggle Switch based in GPIO Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, raspberry-pi3, gpio

Right now I have press switch button based on GPIO for my Raspberry Pi 3B+. How to make it toogle switch 1 time

```
 from gpiozero import LED, Button, Buzzer
from time import sleep

led = LED(19)
SW1 = Button(20)
buzzer = Buzzer(26)

def SW1Pressed():
    global SW1Press
    SW1Press = True
    
SW1.when_pressed = SW1Pressed
SW1Press = True
    
print("Press SW to scan.")

while True:
    if SW1Press == True:
        led.on()
```

Comment: `SW1Press = True` => `SW1Press = not SW1Press`

Comment: also, in the if statement, add `else: led.off()`

Comment: and please don't check like that: `SW1Press == True`. Instead, just `if SW1Press:`